# SCP a remote file with a specific name

Tags: linux, unix, remote, scp

I have a script on a remote server that creates a log each day with the date on the name and need to import it to my local machine everyday, but with my script it transfers all the files and I just want the file of the day.

Remote script that generates the file:

```
day=`date +%Y_%m_%d`

file=daily_$day\.txt

.
.
. >> $file
```

Local script to get the files:

```
day=`date +%Y_%m_%d`

file=daily_$day.txt
report=/path/to/remote

scp user@remote.ip:$report\/$file /path/of/local/
```

Today date is `2013_05_23` and this is what i get:

```
daily_2013_05_22 100%********************************|  1784       00:00

daily_2013_05_23 100%********************************|  1784       00:00
```

It should return only the file with the `2013_05_23` on the name.

Can anyone help?

Tkx

Answer (score 0):

Your script looks ok to me, except for the `\/$file`.

Why the backslash? Get rid of it:

```
scp user@remote.ip:$report/$file /path/of/local/
```